# Add additional information to access token for IdentityServer 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4

For example, client send requests for an access token with the additional field `location: USA`. Where can I store that field, which would then passes back to my server from a client? I mean, that field must present in all requests, but certain values can differs.

Example request:

> POST /connect/token

```
formData: {
  client_id: 'some_id',
  client_secret: 'some_secret',
  grant_type: 'client_credentials',
  scope: 'some_scope',
  location: 'USA' 
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "access_token": "",
  "expires_in": 43200,
  "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Payload of decoded token

```
{
  "nbf": 1517821102,
  "exp": 1517864302,
  "iss": "",
  "aud": [],
  "client_id": "some_id",
  "scope": [ "some_scope" ],
  "location": 'USA'
}
```

I am using IdentityServer 4 on ASP.NET Core

Comment: What do you mean by 'certain values can differ'?

Comment: @RuardvanElburg I mean that location can be not only USA, but e.g. other countries.

Comment: If the location is fixed per client then you can add this as claim in the ClientClaims table.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg that's the problem, location isn't fixed, client can choose any location from the list presented.

Comment: How can the client choose as this is an automated process? And why would it change? If some user interaction is involved you may not be using the right flow. In any case it seems that this information shouldn't be part of the token but should rather be send as parameter on each query. Values that can change frequently shouldn't be stored in the token.

Comment: @RuardvanElburg Imagine a situation, where user choose location at the start of his experience with app, then its location stores, he doesn't need to change it frequently, maybe once a year at best. But it doesn't cancel requirement of location saving.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to implement a custom `IProfileService` and set the `IssuedClaims` property of the `ProfileDataRequestContext`. This should enable you to send custom claims within the access token. [See the documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/reference/profileservice.html?highlight=issuedclaims) for more info.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it!